# How to fill a text area with random numbers

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have a Java application and want to press a button to generate a 7 digit random number and put it into a text area.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    jTextArea1.setText();
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i don't know what to write inside the brackets to get this random number of seven digits on the text area.

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and append 7 random numbers between 0 and 9 using the [`nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method :

```
Random r = new Random();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    sb.append(r.nextInt(10));
jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

first you'll need to inport the java random number library at the top of your code, like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

this code will get you a random number from 1000000 to 9999999, it is a little weird, but take some time trying to figure it out

```
1000000 + (int)(Math.random() * ((8999999) + 1))
```

Try putting that between the parenthasis after setText, like this:

```
jTextArea1.setText(1000000 + (int)(Math.random() * ((8999999) + 1)));
```

For more information about the random function and how it works, looks [here](http://www.cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html)